# Unable to send AJAX request via HTTPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My website has an SSL certificate installed and all incoming requests are re-routed to the secured URL but whenever I make an AJAX request this way this is the response I get back:

> The page at 'https://futminnasugawards18.com/findRide/Offa/Kwara/Bida/Niger/2019-03-15%2015%3A28%3A57/0/1360/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://futminnasugawards18.com/findRide/Offa/Kwara/Bida/Niger/2019-03-15%2015:28:57/0/1360?type=refresh'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

How can I fix this?

```js
var loc = "https://futminnasugawards18.com/findRide/" + $("#start").val() + "/" + $("#state1").val() + "/" + $("#destination").val() + "/" + $("#state2").val() + "/" + $("#date").val() + "/";
var locval = loc.substr(loc.length - 1);
if (locval == "/") {
  var location = loc.substr(0, loc.length - 1);
} else {
  var location = loc;
}

var price = $("#pricerange").val(),
  rating = $("#ratingrange").val(),
  targetUrl = location + "/" + rating + "/" + price + "/",
  targetTitle = "";

//$("#menu-nav a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']").fadeTo(500, 1.0);

window.history.pushState({
  url: "" + targetUrl + ""
}, targetTitle, targetUrl);
$.get(targetUrl, {
  type: "refresh"
}, function(data) {
  $("#placeSearchResults").html(data);
  $(".rideResHide").LoadingOverlay('hide');
});
```

Comment: It sounds like there's a redirect on the server side which you need to update/remove

Comment: As an aside, I would not recommend name a variable 'location' as it conflicts with the built-in location object

Comment: Check network tab and investigate the request... should be able to find useful information there

Comment: @IsaacVidrine i have but nothing useful there

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i only redirected all incoming http request to https

Comment: From the error message it's going the other way

Comment: what other way?

Comment: The error message implies that something is redirecting https to http.

Comment: What does `console.log(targetUrl);` show?

Comment: I suspect this is a server-side issue where you might want to consider using URL rewrites or other routing techniques, rather than issuing redirects.

Comment: @spartyboy... look at the request in network tab. What do the response headers look like? What does the request headers look like? Any 302 status codes? Confirm `targetUrl` is the correct value before making the request.